# How can I stop Cordova CLI / Java from eating up my RAM?

Tags: java, windows, cordova, cordova-cli

I'm building my Android app with Cordova CLI, and every time I run

```
cordova build android [--various args and stuff],
```

the RAM consumption for the Java process in my task manager goes up.

It never seems to go down. I have to then end the task manually. Am I missing some clean afterwards? The build is successful, so I don't see why it does that.

I'm on Windows 10 x64, using Cordova CLI 6.4.0 (Can't downgrade because of plugins).

Comment: What exactly is `[--various args and stuff]`? What happens when running without those? Also, does running the app with `cordova run android` work (detecs plugged device, uses emulator otherwise)?

Comment: The command is
`cordova build android --release --buildConfig=build.json`
Where build.json contains code signing details.

I haven't tested the run command. I don't understand how it's related, but I'll see if I can get it going on my test device.

Comment: UPDATE: Yep, first time I run
`cordova run android` 
 it starts at 300 Mb, and every subsequent run command adds another 20-40 Mb. It never goes down.

I also probably should have said, I'm on Windows.

Comment: AFAIK, there should be no java process left when the build is finished. It looks like the problem is related to the Android SDK rather than Cordova. To verify this, you can do `cordova prepare android` (which just creates the android project), open the project (located in `platforms/android`) in android studio and build/run from there, then check if the RAM issue persists.